# Cannot run scala files from command prompt

Tags: eclipse, scala, cmd, compilation, execution

I could not run a Scala project from command prompt. It was able to get it to work when I wrote the program in Scala Worksheet, but I want to get it to run from Eclipse using CMD. I did:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>scalac Hello_WORLD.scala
error: source file 'Hello_WORLD.scala' could not be found
one error found
```

Then, I tried to skip the compiling and go straight to the execution:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>scala Hello_WORLD
No such file or class on classpath: Hello_WORLD
```

Here is my code that I wrote in Eclipse. I created a Scala Project and a Scala class within the src folder.

```
class Hello_WORLD {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
     println("HELLO!")
  }
}
```

Can you please help me? Please try not to leave rude comments. This is my first time trying out Scala. I would greatly appreciate your help. I tried looking at the Scala documentation and other posts on StackOverflow, but none of them helped my situation. I made sure that the environment variables were configured correctly. If you need any more information, please let me know in the comments.

Regards,

Ani

Comment: have you check the directory you are in? you have to be in same directory as HELLO_WORLD.scala is!

Comment: Please don't tell people how to respond to your question—"try not to leave rude comments" comes across as very condescending, and isn't necessary. It's unlikely anyone will leave rude comments, and if they do we'll flag them.

Comment: Thank you @Travis Brown for your advice.

Comment: @Omid, how do you specify this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in Eclipse:

- From the Package Explorer tab -> Select the project src directory -> Right click -> New -> Scala Application
- From File -> New -> Scala Application

Choosing one of those for the default package, lets me create this:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println( "Hello World")
}
```

Notice that the "main" comes from extending [App](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.App).  It's an `object` instead of a class and you can run it inside of Eclipse via:

- Choosing it in the Package Explorer -> right click -> Run As -> Scala Application
- Run -> Run Configurations -> Scala Applications -> New -> Hello World -> Run

If you want to run that from the command line, you can Export your code to a jar file using:

- Package Explorer tab -> right click -> Java -> Jar file -> browse to choose the name/location of the Jar file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate it. I would vote up if I could :). So I should be creating a Scala application instead of a Scala class from now on?

Comment: There are "Caveats" listed in using the App trait in the documentation, so probably not in every case.  I think it's certainly suitable for general use though.  If you want to pass args to it, you might want to investigate one of several argument parsing libraries for Scala applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all steps you have to take:

1- Install Scala and make sure the path is included in the windows path variable.( to check it, type **scala** in terminal, it should go to scala console
2- cd to directory with HellWorld.scala
3- the code should be this:

```
object HelloWorld extends App{
println("Hello World!")
}
```

4- scalac Helloworld.scala

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A scala programm needs a main class to work like java but if u dont want to define a "main" then you can go for "object" with extending "App". This will work fine. In this case you will not asked to have a "main" class.

```
object FirstProg extends App {
   println("My first prog...!")
}
```